# Cannot resize explorer windows when multitasking [Win10 - 1809]

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, aero-snap, multitasking

I noticed a bug (?) when trying to multitask using two file explorer windows.
I snap two such windows on either side; but unlike other applications, I don't get the resize cursor at the middle (neither the solo resize cursor, nor the vertical dual resize bar).

Is there a way to correct this?

---

My computer configuration is:

- **Edition**: Windows 10 Enterprise (v.1809)
- **OS Build**: 17763.1577

Answer (score 0):

V1809 is an older version of Windows 10 and needs to be upgraded.

For Version 20H2 (current) and Version 21H new (next version), the cursor at the edges and corners of the screen (after Snapping To) is clearly visible and the window(s) and the File Explorer window can be resized (both versions)

**First** try the initial Windows Repair:

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  .

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth .

SFC /SCANNOW and the Restart and test.

**Second** upgrade to current or do a Repair Install from the Media Creation Link.  Update to current will effectively do a Repair and so is preferrable.